# Weak derivative of this function

Tags: derivatives, weak-derivatives

What is the weak derivative of this function:

$(2x-a)^{1/2}1_{2x\geq a}$.

Comment: What is the weak derivative of $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^{1/2} 1_{x > 0}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ of compact support. Compute
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}(2x-a)^{1/2}1_{2x\ge a} \ f'(x)\ dx
& = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int_{a/2+\varepsilon}^\infty (2x-a)^{1/2}f'(x)\ dx \\
& = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}(-(2\varepsilon)^{1/2} f'(a/2+\varepsilon)-\int_{a/2+\varepsilon}^\infty (2x-a)^{-1/2}f(x)\ dx) \\
& = -\int_{a/2}^\infty (2x-a)^{-1/2}f(x)\ dx.
\end{align*}
This implies that the weak derivative of $(2x-a)^{1/2}1_{2x\geq a}$ is $(2x-a)^{-1/2}1_{2x\geq a}$.

Comment: Yes but the OP might be lost with this. Here $g(x) = (2x-a)^{1/2} 1_{x \ge a/2}$ is $C^\infty$ on $x > a/2$ and $x < a/2$. It remains to show it is weak differentiable around $a/2$, ie. its derivative on $(-\infty,a/2)\cup(a/2,\infty)$ is in $L^1_{loc}$